# How and where do hoses connect and run on a 110cc Kazuma Redcat 4wheeler?

Tags: repair, replacements

Bought a 110cc Kazuma Redcat, notice dryrot hoses so I took them all off. Needless to say I never got back to it right away, so I forgot where hoses go, run, and connect to proper parts and places. I have Raider fuel line 5' length- 1/4", and 5' length- 5/16" Raider fuel line. Will this line work for the fuel line, and or All lines needed?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!